# Algorithm Time Complexity Analysis (three nested for loops)

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Here's the code I've implemented in a nutshell. The two inside for loop should have a complexity of `O(n2) where n=vertices`. I just can't figure out the overall time complexity along the outer for loop. I think its gonna be `O( E * n2) where E is the number of edges and n is the number of vertices`.

```
int vertices;

for(int Edges = 0; Edges < vertices-1 ; Edge++)
{
    for (int i=0; i< vertices; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<vertices; j++)
        {
            // TASKS
        } 
}
```

This code is for a prim algorithm. I can post the whole code if you want. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh!!! What is so typical about it!

In your inner loops,you have variables named i & j,so you figured out easily the complexity.

Just with an addition of `EDGE` variable which is not at all different from the other 2,you have got confused! Check the number of iterations!!!

The outer-loop would run `VERTICES-1` iterations.

Therefore, complexity = (VERTICES-1) * (VERTICES) *(VERTICES) = (VERTICES^3) - (VERTICES^2).

Program's complexity would be O(Vertices^3) OR O(n^3) where n=vertices...

Comment: shouldn't it be O( E * n2) where E is the number of edges and n is the number of vertices? Sorry sir I'm a beginner

Comment: @user3490561- nO,THE total number of iterations will guide the complexity. You can say it is running O(n^2*E),but,E itself iterated from 0 to `VERTICES-1` iterations. And,please revisit my answer. Also, I am a student like you,NOT a sir. Please be cool with me.

Comment: You mean that constants are thrown, thus (VERTICES-1) becomes (VERTICES). Accordingly, O(VERTICES * VERTICES * VERTICES) = O(Vertices^3)

Comment: @user3490561- Exactly,for big-O analysis, you can drop constants! You are correct in assuming so.

Comment: Thank you sir... If you teach me something, then you are a sir to me.

Comment: @user3490561-Thanks. But,it is such a whopping OR overwhelming respect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Sigma notation makes things clear:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. However, if you're not very familiar with summations, you can use this tool: http://www.combineditorix.com/